# How can a get a JVM heap dump from Java 5 on Windows without a JDK installed and the process running as a service

Tags: java

This has been made hard for me:

1. Windows, so no signals.
2. Not in a console, so no signals that way.
3. As a service, so perhaps not run in user session.
4. Java 5
5. No JDK, so no jmap, jconsole etc. on machine.
6. App not running JMX.
7. No option to install or reconfigure.
8. Can plug a USB in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK You can't trigger a heap dump with Java 5.0 even if you has complete access to the machine. (Admittedly I haven't used Java 5.0 for more than five years)  With Java 6 you need JMX or trigger a heap dump on an out of memory error.

Some memory profilers may allow you to do a heap dump (of their own format) if you can find one which supports Java 5.0 but you would have to enable profiling from the start and that tended to be relatively slow on Java 5.0 from memory.